# SQL query - how to use exist and not exist conditions at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB`. `TableA` has a column `newValue` and `oldValue`. `TableB` has a column `value`.

I want the following result: get all the rows from `TableA` where `newValue` exist in `TableB` and `oldValue` not exist in `TableB`.

Both tables has many rows so performance is important!

How would you accomplish that in SQL Server 2010/2012?

(u.i.: I found no property title for this question).

**Edit:**

The first  thing I tried is:

```
SELECT newValue, oldValue
FROM TableA
WHERE newValue IN (SELECT value FROM TableB) 
  AND oldValue NOT IN (SELECT value FROM Table B)
```

But this is inefficient and has poor performance on my database. I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2010

Comment: *But this is inefficient and has poor performance on my database* That doesn't mean the problem is with the query, you might benefit from indexes on `value`, and a covering index of `(newValue) INCLUDE (oldValue)` or `(oldValue) INCLUDE (newValue)`.

Comment: I do have indexes on each relevant column as you wrote.

Comment: Do you have three indexes or two? I only propose two.

Comment: try all querys and write times:)

Comment: Here are the proposed indexes: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dca10/2/0 Note that there's not enough data for SQL Server to use `IX_Value` so here's the same thing with index hints so you can see the execution plan: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dca10/3/0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Select Distinct A.*
From TableA A
     Inner Join TableB B on A.newValue = B.Value
Where A.OldValue NOT In (Select Value From TableB)
```

Comment: This isn't sufficient. I still need to filter those rows from TableB where TableA.oldValue not exists.

Comment: This might return duplicates.

Comment: Now `DISTINCT A.*` might fail if there's a `TEXT` column.

Comment: The best solution is the closest one to yours. I used a JOIN + NOT EXIST together. Other solution seemed to be slower. 
So I'll accept this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think avoiding `EXISTS` and `IN` helps with speed here:

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM TableA
    WHERE
        (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TableB WHERE value = newValue) IS NOT NULL
        AND
        (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TableB WHERE value = oldValue) IS NULL
```

Comment: SQL Server's query planner is quite capable, it is entirely possible it will generate equivalent plants for correlated subqueries vs. `(NOT) IN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can exists use exists/not exists

```
SELECT newValue, oldValue
FROM TableA as t1 
where exists(SELECT value FROM TableB as t2 where t1.newValue=t2.value) and 
 not exists(SELECT value FROM TableB as t3 where t1.olvalue=t3.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have indexes on `value`, `newvalue` and `oldvalue`, you can try this:

```
select
    a.newValue, a.oldValue
from TableA as a
where
    a.newValue in (select distinct b.value from TableB as b) and
    a.oldValue not in (select distinct b.value from TableB as b)
```

or `exists`:

```
select
    a.newValue, a.oldValue
from TableA as a
where
    exists (select * from TableB as b where b.value = a.newValue) and
    not exists (select * from TableB as b where b.value = a.oldValue)
```

Comment: Does the `distinct` part of `a.newValue in (select distinct b.value from TableB as b)` change the execution plan in any way? I suspect not.

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
select * from TableA where newValue in (select value from TableB)
union
select * from TableA where oldValue not in (select value from TableB)
```

Comment: this one can return duplicate rows

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with single exist condition.

```
 SELECT newValue, oldValue
 FROM TableA a
 WHERE exists 
 (
  SELECT 1 FROM TableB b 
  where a.newValue = b.value 
  and a.oldValue != b.value)
```

Comment: When you do a downvote, have a habit of adding comment which will help us understand the reason.

Comment: I think downvote is for your answer.Look mine has downvote too even if its the accepted answer  :). In your sub-qurey, it will always select 1 (`SELECT 1 FROM TableB b`). Seems like a typo. Please correct!! Even if you change that I am not sure will this give the expected answer

Comment: @huMptyduMpty. I am using exists here. Only in "IN" clause it checks for values. Exist clause checks for existance of value under condition. So in exists clause we can even do "exist(select null from )". The user who downvoted didnt leave comment. Thats why i added a comment asking for it. Anyhow, thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Mani your query is not equivalent to what the OP's query. (your query will find all rows of table A where the newValue exists in table B and the oldValue is different from newValue, while the OP's query checks the old and new Value against all possible values of B) Perhaps someone downvoted you because of that.